# How to return the results of 7 days during a week

Tags: sql, oracle

My week starts on Saturday and ends on Friday. for example:  6-30-2018 was my first day in the week and July 6th is the last day.

```
select trunc(sysdate,'IW') + Level -  (1+ trunc(sysdate) - trunc(sysdate, 'IW')) 
from dual connect by level < 8;
```

the results keeps on moving when I run above query during the week.  I need it to stay the same.

On July 5th, it returns below.  On July 4th, it returned different results. It moves around the sysdate as it changes day by day.

```
TRUNC(SYSDATE,'IW')+LEVEL-(1+TRUNC(SYSDATE)-TRUNC(SYSDATE,'IW'))
29-JUN-2018 00:00:00 
30-JUN-2018 00:00:00 
01-JUL-2018 00:00:00
02-JUL-2018 00:00:00 
03-JUL-2018 00:00:00 
04-JUL-2018 00:00:00
05-JUL-2018 00:00:00

SELECT TRUNC(to_date('08-Jul-2018', 'dd-Mon-yyyy'), 'IW') + Level - (1+ TRUNC(to_date('08-Jul-2018', 'dd-Mon-yyyy'), 'IW') - TRUNC(to_date('08-Jul-2018', 'dd-Mon-yyyy'), 'IW'))
FROM dual
CONNECT BY level <= 8; --great
```

if I hard code this, the results stays the same. Is there a way I don't have to hard code the date though it seems to work.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

This isn't elegant but seems to give what you are looking for:

```
 WITH "Week Spans" AS
        (
        SELECT
               NEXT_DAY(TRUNC(SYSDATE,'YY')-1,'Saturday') + ((LEVEL - 1) * 7) + 00  AS "Saturday"
              ,NEXT_DAY(TRUNC(SYSDATE,'YY')-1,'Saturday') + ((LEVEL - 1) * 7) + 07 - (1 / (24*60*60))  AS "Following Friday"
        FROM dual
        CONNECT BY LEVEL < 53
        )
  SELECT
        (
        SELECT "Saturday" 
        FROM "Week Spans"
        WHERE SYSDATE BETWEEN "Saturday" AND "Following Friday"
        ) + (LEVEL - 1) AS "Week Day"
  FROM dual
  CONNECT BY LEVEL < 8
  ;
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I ran it. it seems to be working great.    I will test it out as the sysdate changes  and a new week starts to see if it still holds true.  Thank you again !

Comment: You can simulate next week by adjusting "WHERE SYSDATE BETWEEN" to "WHERE SYSDATE + 07 BETWEEN".